# Does Zend framework has a fix version of file structure?

Tags: php, zend-framework

As a newbie of Zend framework, I have a few version-dependent questions on the framework.

1. Does Zend Framework has a fixed file structure (meaning a fixed form of file layout)?
2. If so, does this file structure vary according to framework versions?
3. If so, is there any reference to learn all the differences in file structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend Framework has a

[Recommended Project Structure for Zend Framework MVC Applications](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/manual.html)

- [Overview](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.overview.html)
- [Recommended Project Directory Structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html)
- [Module Structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.filesystem.html)
- [Rewrite Configuration Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/manual.html)

Following this structure makes ZF components work out of the box mostly. You do not have to stick to it though, because all paths are configurable with more or less effort.

For further reference, have a look at the

- [ZF Migration Notes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/migration.html)
- [ZF Default Project Structure Component Proposal](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend+Framework+Default+Project+Structure+-+Wil+Sinclair)

Answer (score 2):

1. No, you have pretty much control over everything, from locations to notations.
2. The recommended structure has pretty much remained the same for a long time. Sometimes there can be some new features that can improve the structure a bit (such as resource autoloaders), but essentially it's the same. And even with such improvements the old structures remain backwards compatible.
3. See previous answer.

Comment: Thanks. Besides looking into Bootstrap.php to see if it extends "Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrapper", is there any quick way to tell right away that it's a Zend project?